# Let's clean up U1 links

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Well, [Ubuntu One is being shutdown and all the information will be deleted](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) so that means that all our posts that use U1 image links instead of imgur and text uploaded will be lost.

Below there's a link that would search some of them. Remember that there are also text files that need to be included in the posts or reuploaded if they are too long, but we should prefer not having to click any link.

https://askubuntu.com/search?q=url%3Aubuntuone.com shows <strike>132</strike>
129 results right now.

If you happen to know another domain or way to find out the urls, just post it.

Comment: Ok. What should we do for zip files?

Comment: @jrg err... why answers have zip files?

Comment: some have non-images/text, like custom compiled libraries.

Comment: e.g. the very first one from that search

Comment: Are we sure we want to use imgur?

Comment: What to do with the frequent "Could not load object" error?

Comment: Sorry to have not posted a link above, for your reference, [here](http://ubuntuone.com/0eyiDuvaOmAi25OlN3wcTX) in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/109621/72576).

Comment: @don.joey What's the problem? imgur is the default image host for all the Stack Exchange sites.. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Aditya Ah. I did not know that. Is imgur owned by SE?

Comment: @don.joey SE doesn't own imgur, but SE has formal arrangements with them.. [See this question on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com) and [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/).

Comment: @Aditya thanks for the info.

Comment: @jrg err... I don't know why an answer needs libraries that can't be compiled using sources. Dunno. I suppose that the answer needs to have a method of how to get the binaries.

Comment: @braiam then we need to do that. There are examples of .zip files that were hosting on Ubuntu One before the shutdown, just look through a few and you'll see them.

Comment: [url:ubuntuone.com site:askubuntu.com - Google 13.300 results](https://www.google.nl/#q=url:ubuntuone.com+site:askubuntu.com)

Comment: @Jobin those are not images, check them out with extreme care.

Comment: @blade19899 That also includes any mentioned of "Ubuntu One".

Comment: I think changing these links can be done programmatically. Can we get SE staff/devs involved?

Comment: Files should be simply removed. (Edit should state that they got removed.) No storage is "forever". || Same thing happens when people link from Dropbox. Or Drive. Or ADrive. And such. Then their account gets removed, they delete the files to free up space, and so on. This only creates new dead files/links.

Comment: I do not think images should be removed - when a (new) user posts a link to an image, instead of using an inline image, I see it as out responsibility to educate him that it is better not to use external storage. In this case, it may not even be obviously external to the user.

Comment: Another aspect is that the external image works fine for a user to get an answer, but it is in out interest to prevent bit rot on images to keep/ensure quality of possibly valuable data, like good questions with detailed answers.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel then you say that we should let them die? What did you interpret?

Comment: No, I think they should be migrated to inline images, or imgur, where inline does not make sense. (Of course, there are images/videos that are just not worth transferring).

Comment: @VolkerSiegel again, what good have "inline" images when the images themself leads to a rot link?

Comment: @Braiam Oh, sorry, I see now I confused some things. Most of the confusion is from misunderstanding the comment "Files should be simply removed." of Shiki as "images should be simply removed.", and answering that without explicit reference to him. Sorry.   (Confusion regarding image handling: I assumed the imgur images are different from the images shown directly in articles.)

Comment: Unless there's a better search than the one provided in the post, all of us reading this could change a few and it might be faster than putting together a programmatic method.  (132 or so divided by the number reading this works out to, what, like 40 apiece? :)

Comment: So...what do we do with the non-image files?

Comment: @Hippo if they are text, just add it to the post. Binaries, remove them and add a way where they can be got.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to start working on this but several of the links are either lost or moves because I keep on getting on several of them when I click **Could not locate object**

I will try to do as many as I can this weekend. If you find another method to search for more let me know.